# How do we throw and catch a RangeError, ReferenceError, TypeError in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, exception, typeerror, referenceerror

I was wondering if any of you have tried catching errors such as RangeError, ReferenceError and TypeError using JavaScript's exception handling mechnism?

For instance for RangeError:

```
try {
var anArray = new Array(-1); 
// an array length must be positive

         throw new RangeError("must be positive!")
}
catch (error) {  
         alert(error.message);
         alert(error.name);
}
finally {
         alert("ok, all is done!");
}
```

In the above case, am i throwing a new RangeError object?

Cos my code example at alert(error.message) doesnt show the user defined message of "must be positive".

What can I do to throw my own RangeError object ( and ReferenceError, TypeError ) ?

Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost a year old, but I figure better late than never. It depends on the browser, but in some instances (*cough*, *cough*, *FIREfox*, *cough*), RangeError inherits the Error object's message property instead of supplying it's own. I'm afraid the only workaround is to throw `new Error("must be positive!")`. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, array indices in JavaScript don't need to be positive since arrays are essentially hash tables here. If you try to access a non-existing key in an array, the result will simply be `undefined`.

You can catch that with a simple condition:

```
if (typeof someArray[foo] !== "undefined") {
    //do stuff
} else {
    //do error handling
    //Here I'm just throwing a simple exception with nothing than a message in it.
    throw new Error('something bad happened');
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "TypeError", though. Please give some more detail.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError

Comment: Just stumbeld upon this, and I have to correct you: `new Array(-1)` IS invalid. While you are correct about indices not having to be positive, the first argument of the `Array` constructor is the number of elements inside the array after creation (all default to `undefined`) and defaults to zero. Obviously you cannot create an array with less than 0 elements in it.
(Also not that using negative indices in Javascript arrays will not adjust the `length` property, as it indicates the highest positive index that has been used. This is why it does make sense in most cases to not allow them)